# Getting error angular.min.js:103 DELETE http://localhost:3000/groceryItem/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

**Server.js file 
    The methods for put and delete are defined here**

```
var express     =   require('express'),
app         =   express(),
mongoose    =   require('mongoose'),
bodyParser  =   require('body-parser'),
Grocery =   require('./server/models/grocery.js'),
db ='mongodb://localhost:27017/grocerylist';

mongoose.connect(db);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + db);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));



app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.get('/groceryItem',function(req,res){
    console.log("get all items find");
    Grocery.find(function(err,item){
            if(err){
                res.send("error occured");
            }else{
                console.log(item);
                res.json(item);
            }
        })
})

app.get('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("get all items find one");
    Grocery.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error occured");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })
})

app.post('/groceryItem',function(req,res){
    Grocery.create(req.body,function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error saving item");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })
})

app.put('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("I am in")
    var query = {
        itemName : req.body.itemName
    };
    Grocery.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},query,function(err,newItem)
   {
        if(err){
                console.log("error occured");
            }else{
                console.log(newItem);
                res.send(newItem);
            }

        });
});

app.delete('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){

    console.log(req.params.id)
    /*Grocery.findOneAndRemove({_id:req.params.id},function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error deleting");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })*/
})

app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
app.use('/lib',express.static(__dirname + '/client/lib'));
app.use('/css',express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/fonts',express.static(__dirname + '/fonts'));
app.use('/views',express.static(__dirname + '/client/views'));

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("I am listening on port 3000")
});


 var express     =   require('express'),
app         =   express(),
mongoose    =   require('mongoose'),
bodyParser  =   require('body-parser'),
Grocery =   require('./server/models/grocery.js'),
db ='mongodb://localhost:27017/grocerylist';

mongoose.connect(db);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + db);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));



app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.get('/groceryItem',function(req,res){
    console.log("get all items find");
    Grocery.find(function(err,item){
            if(err){
                res.send("error occured");
            }else{
                console.log(item);
                res.json(item);
            }
        })
})

app.get('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("get all items find one");
    Grocery.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error occured");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })
})

app.post('/groceryItem',function(req,res){
    Grocery.create(req.body,function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error saving item");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })
})

app.put('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("I am in")
    var query = {
        itemName : req.body.itemName
    };
    Grocery.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},query,function(err,newItem)
   {
        if(err){
                console.log("error occured");
            }else{
                console.log(newItem);
                res.send(newItem);
            }

        });
});

app.delete('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){

    console.log(req.params.id)
    /*Grocery.findOneAndRemove({_id:req.params.id},function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error deleting");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })*/
})

app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
app.use('/lib',express.static(__dirname + '/client/lib'));
app.use('/css',express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/fonts',express.static(__dirname + '/fonts'));
app.use('/views',express.static(__dirname + '/client/views'));

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("I am listening on port 3000")
});
var express     =   require('express'),
app         =   express(),
mongoose    =   require('mongoose'),
bodyParser  =   require('body-parser'),
Grocery =   require('./server/models/grocery.js'),
db ='mongodb://localhost:27017/grocerylist';

mongoose.connect(db);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + db);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));



app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.get('/groceryItem',function(req,res){
    console.log("get all items find");
    Grocery.find(function(err,item){
            if(err){
                res.send("error occured");
            }else{
                console.log(item);
                res.json(item);
            }
        })
})

app.get('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("get all items find one");
    Grocery.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error occured");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })
})

app.post('/groceryItem',function(req,res){
    Grocery.create(req.body,function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error saving item");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })
})

app.put('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("I am in")
    var query = {
        itemName : req.body.itemName
    };
    Grocery.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},query,function(err,newItem)
   {
        if(err){
                console.log("error occured");
            }else{
                console.log(newItem);
                res.send(newItem);
            }

        });
});

app.delete('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){

    console.log(req.params.id)
    /*Grocery.findOneAndRemove({_id:req.params.id},function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error deleting");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })*/
})

app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
app.use('/lib',express.static(__dirname + '/client/lib'));
app.use('/css',express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/fonts',express.static(__dirname + '/fonts'));
app.use('/views',express.static(__dirname + '/client/views'));

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("I am listening on port 3000")
});


var express     =   require('express'),
app         =   express(),
mongoose    =   require('mongoose'),
bodyParser  =   require('body-parser'),
Grocery =   require('./server/models/grocery.js'),
db ='mongodb://localhost:27017/grocerylist';

mongoose.connect(db);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + db);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));



app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.get('/groceryItem',function(req,res){
    console.log("get all items find");
    Grocery.find(function(err,item){
            if(err){
                res.send("error occured");
            }else{
                console.log(item);
                res.json(item);
            }
        })
})

app.get('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("get all items find one");
    Grocery.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error occured");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })
})

app.post('/groceryItem',function(req,res){
    Grocery.create(req.body,function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error saving item");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })
})

app.put('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("I am in")
    var query = {
        itemName : req.body.itemName
    };
    Grocery.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},query,function(err,newItem)
   {
        if(err){
                console.log("error occured");
            }else{
                console.log(newItem);
                res.send(newItem);
            }

        });
});

app.delete('/groceryItem/:id',function(req,res){

    console.log(req.params.id)
    /*Grocery.findOneAndRemove({_id:req.params.id},function(err,item){
        if(err){
            res.send("error deleting");
        }else{
            console.log(item);
            res.json(item);
        }
    })*/
})

app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
app.use('/lib',express.static(__dirname + '/client/lib'));
app.use('/css',express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/fonts',express.static(__dirname + '/fonts'));
app.use('/views',express.static(__dirname + '/client/views'));

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("I am listening on port 3000")
});

**Angular Code**





 $scope.updateItem = function() {


    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.put('/groceryItem/' ,+ id , $scope.groceryItem) .then(function 
 (response) {
        //$scope.groceryItem = response.data;
        alert("ssss"+ $scope.groceryItem)
        $location.path("/");
    })
    }
 **The delete method**

$scope.deleteItem = function(id) {
    var id = id;
    console.log(id);
    //alert("ssss"+ id)
    $http.delete('/groceryItem/' ,+ id ) //.then(function (response) {
        //$scope.groceryItem = response.data;

        //$location.path("/");
        //$route.reload();
    //})
}
```

> **Error on console on  updating a data**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token N
at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\WebstormProjects\GroceryList\node_modules\body-
parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\WebstormProjects\GroceryList\node_modules\body-
parser\lib\read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback 
(C:\xampp\htdocs\WebstormProjects\GroceryList\node_modules\body-
parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
at done (C:\xampp\htdocs\WebstormProjects\GroceryList\node_modules\body-
parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd 
(C:\xampp\htdocs\WebstormProjects\GroceryList\node_modules\body-
[enter image description here][1]parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)**
```

[The error that appears on the console when trying to delete and update a data][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIHvz.png

Comment: Typo. `$http.delete('/groceryItem/' ,+ id )` should be `$http.delete('/groceryItem/' + id )`. You have the same mistake on your `put` as well.

Comment: Thanks a ton... the issue is resolved now :)